# Is it possible to use the same base hostname for 2 Vue.js project?

Tags: vue.js

I currently developing 2 different projects, one is in `http://localhost:8080` and the other one is in `http://localhost:8081`

but is it possible to have my second project to use `http://localhost:8080/second` instead of `http://localhost:8081`?

if it possible, how can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

*This may break hot module reloading of the second project*

You can setup a [proxy](https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options.html#server-proxy) for in your dev server. For vite (which is preferred for vue3), you can set it in your vite config of the first project:

```
export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    proxy: {
      '/second': 'http://localhost:8081/second/',
    },
    …,
  },
  …,
}
```

For vue cli you can do the same, using `devServer.proxy`, [see docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#devserver-proxy).

Then, you have to [change your server base](https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options.html#server-base) to `/second/` in the second project. Also you have to add the base dir to your router file, if you are using vue-router. Like: `history: createWebHistory('/second/'),`.

You have to start the dev server of both projects, but now you go to the second project via port 8080.

Comment: Notice that this doesn't take devserver socket into account, it also needs to be proxied

Comment: @EstusFlask can you please clearify a bit more, I don’t understand what you mean by that.

Comment: The OP doesn't explain the setup and it's unknown if the projects use Vue CLI. But normally all up-to-date devservers use websocket connection to provide live reload. If you don't handle it, there won't be live reload in development

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of the dev server using a websocket for hot reloading.